# Play rhythmic sound when view is spinning

Tags: swift, rotation, core-animation, caanimation

I want to play a rhythmic sound when the view is rotating, dependent on speed. Here I have the spin animation for UIview.

```
    var spinAnimation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
spinAnimation.fromValue = 0
spinAnimation.toValue =  NSNumber(double: 10.0+Double(arc4random_uniform(360))*M_PI * 3)
spinAnimation.duration = 5
spinAnimation.delegate = self
spinAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

layer.addAnimation(spinAnimation, forKey: "SpinAnimation")
```

How do I feedback the user about the rotation speed via sound?

Comment: you want to play rhythmic sound when view is spinning or give the rotation speed to the user. pl. clarify.

Comment: I want to play sound based on rotation speed . means if view is spinning fast i need play sound loud . it is slowing down then i need to play less sound.

Answer (score 0):

In the apple developer document they have given an option to change the volume of the music, pl. refer the the below url

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html

and you can use the below code snippet for your reference

```
var spinnigSpeedMusic= AVAudioPlayer()
var spinningMusicUrl:NSURL =    NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("spinningSpeed", withExtension: ".mp33")
spinnigSpeedMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:spinningMusicUrl, error: nil)      

spinnigSpeedMusic.prepareToPlay()
spinnigSpeedMusic.play()
spinnigSpeedMusic.volume = 0.1 // this value can be changed from 0.0 to 1, based on the rotation speed.
```

Comment: Here spinnigSpeedMusic.volume need to change based on rotation speed , I need to manage sound according to spinning. the  spinnigSpeedMusic.volume  need to change between 
animationDidStart:
animationDidStop:finished: Delegates